# file-system "snapshot on write" options?

Tags: filesystems, snapshot, integrity

I would like some help identifying software, (file systems, fuse modules, etc) which can accomplish retention of (over)written files;

For example, I could author a fuse shim and mount it in-place of some high-retention directory like a project's network share, and have this shim trigger a file-system snapshot on (after) write. 
Is there a better or more standardized way to accomplish this? This seems like a natural feature of a COW file system, I hope I am simply ignorant of built in tools to access this granularity.

I'm under the impression the most standardized way to approach this is to do periodic snapshots (daily/hourly) however I would really like on-write-event granularity.

Comment: see https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs

Comment: see http://fsvs.tigris.org/

Comment: I have considered a vcs-db-as-a-file-system, this is probably a decent option. I am not specifically interested in complete history retention, however its probably affordable to have and does simply defining what data is disposable (as "none of it")

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [log-structured file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system); these append writes, which effectively means that they provide continuous snapshots. Older “snapshots” are lost when disk space needs to be freed, but even that can usually be configured so you can define a snapshot-preservation policy.

Most Unix-style systems have one or more implementations of such file systems available. On Linux, you could look at [NILFS2](https://nilfs.sourceforge.io/en/) which is built-in to the kernel and supported on most distributions.